# Array of objects in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.items.push(items);
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        {{value.ItemId}}
    </div>
</div>
```

How to avoid nested ng-repeat when iterating through an array of objects/arrays?

Comment: In the second line, is `items` another array of items?

Comment: yes, items is array of objects.

Comment: why are you adding items again to items?

Comment: I'm assigning scope variable with array that I get from server.

Comment: I'm pushing new array into scope variable that is type of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't push one array into another, use [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
$scope.items = [];
angular.extend($scope.items, items);


<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in items">
    {{item.ItemId}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$resource` to get your items from the server?

`$resource` returns a promise that can be assigned to your scope and will be populated with the data by Angular automatically.

```
var Items = $resource('/yourUrl');
```

[$resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

After you implement your ajax call as a resource, you can simply do `$scope.items = Items.query()`.